# Firebase: Re-authenticate the current user inside a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing a cloud function for updating the current user's password.

Basically, the logic I want to follow is:

```
(Client side)
 0. Complete form and submit the data (current password and new password).

(Backend) 
 1. Get the current user email from the callable function context.
 2. Re-authenticate the current user using the provided current password.
   2.1. If success, change the password and send a notification email.
   2.2. Else, throw an error.
```

Here is my current code:

```
const { auth, functions } = require("../../services/firebase");
...

exports.updatePassword = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  .runWith({ memory: "1GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const { currentPassowrd, newPassword } = data;

    const { email, uid: userId } = context.auth.token;

    if (!userId) {
      // throw ...
    }

    try {
      // 
      // Problem: `firebase-admin` authentication doesn't include
      // the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method...
      //
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, currentPassowrd);

      await auth.updateUser(userId, {
        password: newPassword,
      });

      sendPasswordUpdateEmail(email);
    } catch (err) {
      // ...
      throw AuthErrors.cannotUpdatePassword();
    }
  });
```

My problem is that the `firebase-admin` package doesn't include the `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, and I need a way to handle this, to check that "currentPassword" is correct, inside my function.

My other option, if the one I have described is not possible, is to update the password using the firebase sdk in the client side, and then to call a firebase function to send the notification email.

Comment: You'd need to look at the rest API https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password - otherwise I would look at the client side option to be honest with you https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email

Comment: Yeah, as the Firebase auth `updatePassword` method **requires** a recent login, or it will throw an error, I think the client side option is a good choice. Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why do you need to re-authenticate the user in the Cloud Function. If you get a value for `context.auth.uid` it means that the user is authenticated in the front-end and you can therefore safely call the `updateUser()`method.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec just an extra security step. Imagine the user left his device opened, and someone updates his password. That’s why I am using a “currentPassword” field, to re-authenticate before updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you don't need to re-authenticate the user in the Cloud Function: If you get a value for `context.auth.uid` in your Callable Cloud Function, it means that the user is authenticated in the front-end and you can therefore safely call the `updateUser()` method.

If you want to deal with the case when the user left his device opened, and someone updates his password, as explained in the comments under your question, I would suggest you use the [`reauthenticateWithCredential()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#reauthenticatewithcredential_60f8043) method in the front-end, which re-authenticates a user using a fresh credential.

Do as follows:

```
import {
    EmailAuthProvider,
    getAuth,
    reauthenticateWithCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth'

const email = auth.currentUser.email;
// Capture the password value
// e.g. via a pop-up window
const password = ...;

const auth = getAuth();
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    email,
    password
);
await reauthenticateWithCredential(
    auth.currentUser, 
    credential
);

// If no error is thrown, you can call the Callable Cloud Function, knowing the user has just re-signed-in.
```